Updated pdfbox from 2.0.26 to 3.0.2
I have updated the pdfbox from 2.0.26 to 3.0.2 but I'm getting this Exception and PDF report is not generated after completing the test

How to get rid of this exception and make the pdfbox to generate the report?

You appear to have forgotten to follow the migration guide.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I have read the pdfbox migration guide but don't to how to add or cache that HELVETICA font manually.

use this instead, as described in the migration guide:
new PDType1Font(FontName.HELVETICA)


I tried this before. I don't know where to add this line. Could you tell me?

I'm using extentreports-cucumber7-adapter for generating pdf reports. Due to this error I can't generate the PDF Report.

If you're not using PDFBox as a direct dependency, then something else is (indeed, cucumber-pdf-report is). The versions 2 and 3 are incompatible, i.e. the API has changed. Update to 2.0.31 instead and you're fine. The 2.0 version is still maintained at this time.
